# NetworkManager.conf reset to "404: NotFound" every time service is restarted

Tags: opensuse, networkmanager, home-assistant

i encountered a problem while working with the NetworkManager service on my Raspberry pi 4, i am running it with openSUSE Tumbeweed JeOS, so the default is not networkmanager but wicked, i started to notice that every time i tried to restart it the service failed.
Watching through the logs i noticed this:
`Oct 31 16:49:37 suse-server NetworkManager[2966]: <warn>  [1635698977.7227] config: Default config file invalid: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf: Key file contains line “404: Not Found” which is not a key-value pair, group, or comment`

Basically every time NetworkManager is restarted something overwrites the config file, probably with a predefined template from GitHub (when you open a invalid link in raw.github.com you get 404: Not Found), i temporarily switched back to wicked but i need to resolve this problem because i need to run HASS.IO, which unfortunately supports only NetworkManager.

Comment: I have the same issue today :/ Did you found solution?